# Adding CSS custom properties dynamically to svelte components 3.38.0

Tags: javascript, css, properties, svelte, svelte-3

Svelte added support for passing CSS custom properties to a component in 3.38.0

Which allows us to pass a css property like shown below.

```
<Drawer --test1="red">
```

Technically it makes a div like this around your component code:

```
<div style="display: contents; --test: red;">
```

What I would like to do is to pass multiple without having to define them like --test-1="X" --test-2="Z" etc.

I would like to place them in an object:

```
let test = {
    '--test-1': "X",
    '--test-2': "Z"
};
```

And let the keys be rendered with there values.

The question is, is there a way to achieve this?

Link to REPL with a way to do this would be great.

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: @Auroratide I just tried https://svelte.dev/tutorial/spread-props in my own project unfortunately it only works with props of a component. The newly added support for the CSS custom properties is triggered when svelte sees -- in the component declaration. Still it would be great if it worked like the spread-props

Comment: Yeah I had tried that and saw the same; there's no documentation right now, so I'm parsing through the PR itself to see if there's any possibility of this, as defining a reusable set of values seems particularly powerful.

Comment: @Auroratide It's very powerful indeed and quite handy for svelte components that get imported from other libraries, especially if they have TS support because they can define all possible properties in a interface or type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is currently possible. It would be useful, so you should [open a feature request](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/new/choose).

In the meantime, you can solve this yourself with a custom wrapper component. See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5a75758435f34b9face998b89014df49?version=3.38.2) (relevant code below).

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import Example from './Example.svelte'; 
    import CustomPropWrapper from './CustomPropWrapper.svelte';
    
    const customProps = {
        '--first-color': 'red',
        '--second-color': 'green'
    }
</script>

<!-- longhand way -->
<Example --first-color={firstColor} --second-color={secondColor}></Example>

<!-- pass as an object using a wrapper -->
<CustomPropWrapper {customProps}>
    <Example />
</CustomPropWrapper>

<!-- CustomPropWrapper.svelte -->
<script>
    export let customProps = {};
    
    // create an inline style string
    $: style = Object.entries(customProps).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => `${acc}; ${key}: ${value}`, '');
</script>

<div {style}>
    <slot />
</div>

<style>
    div {
        display: contents;
    }
</style>

<!-- Example.svelte -->
<p class="first">
    I'm the first paragraph
</p>
<p class="second">
    I'm the second paragraph
</p>

<style>
    .first {
        color: var(--first-color);
    }
    
    .second {
        color: var(--second-color);
    }
</style>
```